# The history of Remoting and WCF/coreWCF

Tags: wcf, .net-5, grpc-java, .net-remoting

1. Remoting

This page "[Remoting APIs are obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/remoting-apis-obsolete)" doesn't describe reasons for the decision to obsolete the technogy.

My understanding is that Remoting is related to AppDomain technology, which is also obsoleted. But may be also other reasons exist?

Remoting was able to use shared memory (in GenuineChannels library opensourced with time).

There also was a plugin technology (MAF - Managed Add in Framework), which depended on Remoting, how these features are implementing now with gRPC?

2. WCF/netWCF

Why WCF and netWCF are obsolete?

Is the transition to HTTP/2 the main reason to their deprecation? ("[Why we recommend gRPC for WCF developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/why-grpc)")

Comment: In my opinion, the development of technology cannot be separated from the daily use of a large number of, a less popular, less used technology is difficult to become popular, WCF may be its own technology does not conform to the concept of the public, or may be due to the development of the company's decision-making problems caused by no attention.